# getting variable from javascript to php

Tags: php, jquery

I have a simple combo box whose value I can get in JavaScript.
I am doing that so I don't need to refresh the page.
Also I want to use the selected value to do some conditional branching after combo box so how do I get the value of combo box from JavaScript to my variable `$change`.

```
echo '<select id="combo_1">';
echo '<option value="2">Submative</option>';
echo '<option value="1">formative</option>';
echo '</select>';
```

Below is my JavaScript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#combo_1').change(function(){

        });

    });

    </script>
```

Here I want to do `$change = $(this).val()`, but obviously I cant do it like this.
Any suggestions?
i want to do it on the same page without refreshing or without submitting
my url kinda look like this

```
 http://localhost/lms/grade/report/userdef/index.php
```

and i want it to be on click action 
cuz depending on the choice of combobox 2 very different procedures will be called

Comment: You can use ajax method to send variable value http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ When do you want to send this value? I mean which event? On combo.change()? What do you want to do next with this value? Refresh page or display new content on current page?

Comment: Are you thinking this on same page or different page? if you are with different page then use ajax and if you are second then also use ajax with same file name in ajax url option.

Comment: @matty yes when combo box will change value i just want to do a comparison like if( $change===1) perfrom this function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're gonna want to use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post) and submit the form, then you can access the returned data without ever refreshing the page.

Basically:

## HTML

```
<select name="combo" id="combo_1">
    <option value="2">Submative</option>
    <option value="1">formative</option>
</select>
```

## JavaScript

```
$('#combo_1').change(function() {
    $.post('calcScript.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

in PHP, you can access your combo data via `$_POST['combo']`.

Comment: i have multiple comboboxes so i cannot use %_post i guess as it will require me to submit and all my comboboxes are interdependent

Comment: The select box name can be an array: `name="combo[0]`, `name="combo[1]"` and then they would be accessible in the same script via `$_POST['combo'][0]` etc. You can submit all the select boxes at once if they are in the same `form` element by serializing `form` itself when using `$.post` (like so: `$('#myform').serialize()`)

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {

  $('#combo_1').change(function(){
        var combo_1 = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'ajax.php',
                data: {'combo_1':combo_1},
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data)
                }
            });
  });

 });

 </script>
```

---

ajax.php

---

```
 if( isset($_GET['combo_1]) ) {
    echo $change = $_GET['combo_1'];
 }
```

Comment: i want to do it in a single file without sumbiting or refreshing

Comment: @stacy m alina change ajax.php page to your page index.php

Comment: its not working as i am passing it to same page and its not refreshing so i dont know where to put isset code as its not working if i put it in start of file

Answer (score 0):

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
url: './filename.php',
    beforeSend: function(){
        //If you want to do something 
},
data: 'data='$('#combo_1').val(), //Optional '&data2='+value+'&datan='+value,
    success: function(msg){
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
$val = $_POST['data'];
return 'received successfully';
```

This will alert 'received successfully'